# How to set up a cron job to run 8 am on Tuesday and 4:30 PM on Friday every week

Tags: cron

I need to set up a cron job to run 8 am on Tuesday and 4:30 PM on Friday every week.

Could anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference, you will see this image:

[image]

Every week 8 AM Tuesday:

**0 8 * * 1**

4:30 PM Friday:

**30 16 * * 4**

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. sorry just a follow up question, can we combine both of them into one ? For example if I have to run on both weekdays at 8 AM every week , I would write something like 0 8 * * 1,4. But the problem is I have 2 different time for both weekdays .

Comment: @user2384052 you can have several lines for the same script, which together specifies it to run at all the times. So, if you have a line of **0 8 * * 1 somescript** and another line of **30 16 * * 4 somescript**, then both time specifications will be taken into account and you will reach your exact goal. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a cron job to run at 8 AM on Tuesday and 4:30 PM on Friday every week, you'll need to create two separate cron entries in your crontab file.

The crontab format is as follows:

```
* * * * * command
```

- Day of the week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)

  Month (1 - 12)

  Day of the month (1 - 31)

  Hour (0 - 23)

  Minute (0 - 59)

Here's how you can set up the cron job for your requirements:

For 8 AM on Tuesday:

```
0 8 * * 2 command
```

For 4:30 PM on Friday:

```
30 16 * * 5 command
```